# google VR framebuffer for water rendering

Tags: android, google-vr

enter code here

I am trying to implement water rendering on GvrView.StereoRenderer on     Android using the last google GVR sdk. For this i need to retreive reflection and refraction image into a frame buffer.

So i tried different méthode to get a result.

1) i cannot bind the water frame buffer in any of these to method "onNewFrame" and "onDrawEye". I always get black screen when rendering(i have tested my frame buffer whithout GVR and it work well). So i tried to use GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING,...) to switch the frame buffer but i got this error :

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj == null
 in call to GetIntField
 from void android.opengl.GLES20.glGetIntegerv(int, java.nio.IntBuffer)

"GLThread 46371" prio=5 tid=20 Runnable
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c66640 self=0x7b690b9600
| sysTid=4963 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b65bff450
| state=R schedstat=( 10115620317 57382805 1227 ) utm=923 stm=88 core=5 HZ=100
| stack=0x7b65afd000-0x7b65aff000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
at android.opengl.GLES20.glGetIntegerv(Native method)
at com.example.user.googleVR.MyGLRenderer.onFinishFrame(MyGLRenderer.java:608)

enter code here
```

2) so i have tried to test the water frame buffer inside the "onFinishFrame" methode. The frame buffer can be executed but the rendering is wrong for many reason :

```
  - I need to reorganize the drawing for the farest mesh to the closer mesh.
    if i render my skybox last i only see the sky. 
    So i need to draws it first and after the other mesh. 
    But at the end i got the transparency color on preview drawed mesh. 
    Even enabling GL_DEPTH_TEST and disabling GL_BLEND do not change nothing.  

enter code here
```

So i would like to know if it is possible to use other frame buffer during the stréoréoscopic rendering "onNewFrame" and "onDrawEye". And how can i manage to do it because google vr documentation said it can be done :

```
public abstract void onDrawEye (Eye eye)

Requests to draw the contents from the point of view of an eye.

If distortion correction is enabled the GL context will be set to draw into a framebuffer
backed by a texture at the time of this call, 
so if an implementor need to change the framebuffer for some rendering stage 
then the implementor must reset the framebuffer to the one obtained via 
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, ...) afterwards.
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code here

I found the solution. The probleme was comming from the use of the GLES20.glGetIntegerv. In fact there is two GLES20.glGetIntegerv in the GLES20.

```
public static native void glGetIntegerv(
    int pname,
    java.nio.IntBuffer params
);

AND

public static native void glGetIntegerv(
    int pname,
    int[] params,
    int offset
);
enter code here
```

So if i use the second glGetIntegerv everything is working fine. Frame buffer can then be use inside the onDrawEye(Eye eye).

So ! sorry for the post. But it can be helpfull too other develloper to know it.

Regards